# Usando a função "as numeric" no RStudio

Tags: funções, r

Olá! Eu estou tentando criar uma nova variável binária a um banco de dados já existente usando o seguinte código:

`leaders$warbefore <- as.numeric(leaders$interwarbefore == '1', leaders$civilwarbefore == '1')`

"Leaders" é o nome do banco de dados já existente e "warbefore" é a nova variável que eu criei.

Quando eu uso o código acima, significa que a nova variável que eu criei,"warbefore", é igual a 1 caso as variáveis selecionadas, "interwarbefore" e"civilwarbefore", sejam **ambas** igual a 1.

No entanto, eu gostaria que a variável "warbefore" seja igual a 1 quando "interwarbefore" for igual 1 **OU** quando "civilwarbefore" for igual a 1.

No código que eu estou usando o requisito é que ambas as variaveis sejam iguais a 1, mas eu quero que quando apenas uma delas for igual a 1, "warbefore" também seja 1.

Alguem pode me ajudar a reformular o código? Obrigado

Comment: Tente usar o operador or `|`,  `leaders$warbefore <- as.numeric(leaders$interwarbefore == '1' | leaders$civilwarbefore == '1')` se não der certo você pode tentar a função `ifelse` também `leaders$warbefore <- ifelse(leaders$interwarbefore == '1' | leaders$civilwarbefore == '1', 1, 0)`

Comment: Era isso mesmo, Jorge! Muito obrigado, querido!!!